# Unable to fetch message from EditText in Customized AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have created a custom layout for AlertDialog which contains a EditText. The Alertdialog has 2 buttons one for Submit and other for Cancel. When I click submit, I want to fetch the message from EditText and display in Logcat. I am getting a NullPointerException when I click Submit button. Somehow I am failing to fetch the message. Please point out where am I going wrong?

custom Layout file: dialog_reportbug

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reportbug"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/reportbug"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >    
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code in my java file:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_reportbug, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Bug Report")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setView(dialoglayout)
        .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                EditText report = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reportbug);
                String msg = report.getText().toString();
                Log.d("Msg",msg);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // do something

            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
EditText report = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reportbug);
```

to :

```
EditText report = (EditText) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.reportbug);
```

Because `report` is in `dialoglayout`, **not** in your activity's layout.

Comment: You welcome. Dont forget to mark it as answer :) U need to do it everytime u inflate a view, and want to use the inflated view's component.